# Generate SSH Key Using java

Tags: java, ssh, putty

I tried to generate the SSH key using the following code

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
         keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
         KeyPair keyPair=keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

         RSAPublicKey publicKey=(RSAPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic();
         RSAPrivateKey privateKey=(RSAPrivateKey)keyPair.getPrivate();

         String base64PubKey = Base64.encodeBase64String(publicKey.getEncoded());
         ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
         dos.writeInt("ssh-rsa".getBytes().length);
         dos.write("ssh-rsa".getBytes());
         dos.writeInt(publicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray().length);
         dos.write(publicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray());
         dos.writeInt(publicKey.getModulus().toByteArray().length);
         dos.write(publicKey.getModulus().toByteArray());
         String publicKeyEncoded = new String(
                                    Base64.encodeBase64(byteOs.toByteArray()));
         String key =  "ssh-rsa " + publicKeyEncoded + " ";
         System.out.println("Public Key ------");
         System.out.println(key);


         System.out.println("------------------------------");
         System.out.println("Private key");
         System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64(privateKey.getEncoded()));
```

Now, When I store the content of private key in a file and trying to validate it with putty it says invalid format of private key.

Could you guys help me out on this, some how I missing the private key format so putty is not recognizing it.

Comment: Generate one key using puttygen and check the differences. Putty is using its own format.

Answer (score 1):

Putty is unable to recognize OpenSSH formatted keys -- they must first be converted into the Putty style using Puttygen.

*There is a Debian/Ubuntu package for this conversion:*

```
apt-get install putty-tools
puttygen openssh_formattted_key -o putty_formatted_key.ppk
```

You *might* be able to investigate this and figure out how the keys are converted, or run the command as a process from inside your code.

*On Windows, the Puttygen GUI is available for this:*

https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/

Download Link: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe

If you want to use this key generated *directly*, I would suggest you use something like MINGW32/MINGW64, Cygwin, etc. which allow you to use the ssh command in Command Prompt or some other terminal-like window.

Comment: (comment removed, I expanded it to another answer)

Answer (score 1):

As noted putty uses only its own 'PPK' format which can be converted by **puttygen** -- but only from the 'commercial' SSH.com format (not applicable here) and the formats used by OpenSSH (before 6.5) which are the **'legacy' formats** originally used by OpenSSL, **NOT** the [PKCS8 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208) format used by OpenSSL since about 2000 and used by Java crypto.

(1) If you have or can get BouncyCastle, see [How can I export a (PKCS#8?) private key in Putty or Puttygen readable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417723/how-can-i-export-a-pkcs8-private-key-in-putty-or-puttygen-readable-format)  to create a file you can read into puttygen.

(2) Else if you have or can get openssl commandline, write the PKCS8 from Java *in correct 'PEM'* which is base64 *with linebreaks at 19 groups (76 chars) or less and header and trailer* for type `PRIVATE KEY` (NOT `RSA PRIVATE KEY` also not `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`), then run that through `openssl rsa` (NOT `openssl pkey`) to convert to legacy, and read that into puttygen.

(3) Else your choices are less good. Probably the best is to unpack the PKCS8 format to get the 'legacy' format something like this:

```
byte[] pk8 = privateKey.getEncoded();
if( pk8[0]!=0x30 || pk8[1]!=(byte)0x82 ) error;
if( 4 + (pk8[2]<<8 | (pk8[3]&0xFF)) != pk8.length ) error;
if( pk8[4]!=2 || pk8[5]!=1 || pk8[6]!= 0 ) error;
if( pk8[7] != 0x30 || pk8[8]==0 || pk8[8]>127 ) error;
// could also check contents of the AlgId but that's more work
int i = 4 + 3 + 2 + pk8[8];
if( i + 4 > pk8.length || pk8[i]!=4 || pk8[i+1]!=(byte)0x82 ) error;
byte[] old = Arrays.copyOfRange (pk8, i+4, pk8.length);
String b64 = /*** encode old to base64, linebreaks optional for puttygen *****/
System.out.println ("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
System.out.println (b64); // or print if (final) EOL already added
System.out.println ("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
```

Put that output in a file and read into puttygen.