# SSH compatible private key

Tags: java, ssh, rsa

Can anyone tell me how to generate SSH compatible private keys from Java's RSAPrivateKey? I looked into many posts but not working for me.

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

        Writer out = new FileWriter(outfile);
        String encodedPrivateKey = encoder.encodeToString(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded());
        out.write(privKeyPrepend);
        out.write(encodedPrivateKey);
        out.write(privKeyAppend);
        out.close();
```

Comment: Which implementation(s) of SSH? There are several, and they don't all use the same privatekey files. For that matter some versions of Java, notably Android, differ in implementing crypto. Poss dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417723/how-can-i-export-a-pkcs8-private-key-in-putty-or-puttygen-readable-format